# Site takes for ever to load and then i get "Uncaught SoapFault exception"

Tags: php, mysql, soap

Trying to send data to a sql database using a soap service. But my site only loads and after 30s gets this error:

```
Warning: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in soapclient.php Stack trace: #0 
[internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('addUser', Array) #2 {main} thrown in soapclient.php


Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in soapclient.php on line 30
```

Soap Client

```
<?php

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $options = array('location' => "http://localhost/fellotest/soap/soap_client.php", 
                    'uri' => 'http://localhost',
                    'trace'=>1);

    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120)

    try{
        $client = new SoapClient(null, $options);
        $client->addUser($first_name, $last_name, $username, $password);
    }
    catch(SoapFault $ex){
        echo "FAULT </br>";
        var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
        var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
        var_dump($ex);
    }

?>
```

Soap server

```
<?php

    include('helpers\security.php');
    include('includes\shared\ez_sql_core.php');
    include('includes\mysqli\ez_sql_mysqli.php');

    // Setting up Soap Service
    $options = array('uri' => 'http://localhost');
    $server = new SoapServer(null, $options)

    //connecting and adding a user to database
    function addUser($first_name, $last_name, $username, $password){

        // For security reasons
        $info = new security();

        // Connect to database
        $db = new ezSQL_mysqli($info::$user, $info::$password, $info::$dbName, $info::$host);
        if(!$db){
            die('Could not connect to database');
        }
        // add user to database
        $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO `user`(`first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password`) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$username', '$password')");
        if(!$insert){
            echo "Error while registering";
        }
        else{
            echo "Register Successful";
        }
    }

    // To handle client
    $server->handle();

?>
```

It seems like there is some process that gets caught in an infinite loop or something. But i cant figure out what or where!

Comment: You're using try-catch block but still the SoapFault isn't being catch: **Warning: Uncaught SoapFault exception**. Try to comment out the $client->addUser call. Does the warning still appear?

Comment: @OfirBaruch No, so the error seems to lay there!

Comment: Can you mention which line is **on line 30** on soapclient.php?

Comment: Sry thats a typo from me. It says line 14. Which is the `$client->addUser` call

Comment: but when you've commented out this line - the same errors/warning appear?

Comment: No, when I commented it out. I get to a blank page (it works).

Answer (score 0):

Now that we know that the problem is in the addUser function, Let's start by understand where the problem is.

@SoapServer.php
Replace:

```
   // To handle client
    $server->handle();
```

With:

```
$server->addFunction("addUser");
try {
    $server->handle();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $server->fault('Sender', $e->getMessage());
}
```

Further more, in both files, add a slash to the localhost uri.

**Update 1:**

Comment out all the block code in the function.
So there would be only:

```
function addUser($first_name, $last_name, $username, $password){
 return 1;
     }
```

**Update 2:**

Since you're still getting the error, comment out those lines:

```
include('helpers\security.php');
include('includes\shared\ez_sql_core.php');
include('includes\mysqli\ez_sql_mysqli.php');
```

Update 3:

Still the error still appears the path for the SOAPSERVER is wrong or it's down. Consider the following in `soapclient.php`:

```
    // Add another option to the array.
$options = array( .... .....,
'connection_timeout' => 300);

//Cache
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

//And also increase the default_socket_timeout.
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300)
```

Comment: Continue to update 2 (still leaving the addUser function only with return 1;)

Comment: Update 2: Same error, still. Btw, was this what you ment with an extra slash? `http://localhost/` or `http:///localhost`

Comment: Meant at the end. If you still get the same error i'm afraid that you're might using the wrong path for the soapserver file or the soapserver is down.

Comment: I edited my path in clients to `http://fellotest/soap/soap_client.php` and now I get to the catch block atleast. The error I get now is: `object(SoapFault)#2 (9) { ["message":protected]=> string(25) "Could not connect to host".....`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134321/discussion-between-ofir-baruch-and-felix-rosen).